# What is a Drawable?

Tags: android, drawable

I'm new in Android dev and I have a ridiculous question..

I read this [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) but I didn't understand everything (because I speak french, not english).

Well.. can anyone explain me with simply words what is a Drawable?

Thank you, best regards.

Comment: Thank you NAVEED, but I tried to use Google Traduction before posting. And the result of the traduction is simply incomprehensive. But I have understand what is a Drawable now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drwable are something that can be drawn on screen for examples images that are drawn on screen.

See this location  **res/drawable-hdpi or res/drawable-mdpi or res/drawable-ldpi** in your project folder , they all are some types of drawables location where we keep our drawables .

Comment: Okey I see.. So if I want to modify an image, I must set it with setImageDrawable before? I can't modify and Image without setting it Drawable?

Comment: Yes , to use any image you must keep it in your drawable folders mannually.

Comment: Thank you, it's OK for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically any object that is able to be drawn to the screen